# Creating form in Jasmine test

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to test my input field component. But in order to do that I need to have a form created, because my component must be part of the form. Example from storybook:

```
    ...args,
    form: new FormGroup({
        fieldText: new FormControl('Hello'),
    }),
},
template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
        <neom-field-text formControlName="fieldText">
        </neom-field-text>
    </form>
`,
```

There I create a form which I then use to wrap my component into it. Can I do something similar in Jasmine?

Comment: Yes, you can do exactly the same - create a parent component to wrap the one you want to test, and render _that_.

Comment: Do you have any example how to do it?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-inside-a-test-host